# "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots)" when using purrr::accumulate, "column can't be converted from numeric to list"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I want to add a column `valueList` to my data frame. Grouped by `id`, it should show the cumulative vector of `value` up to that point. See example below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,3,2,3,5,6),
                 value=c(58,61,59,49,36,35,39,23,75,73,43,43,13,54,23,12))

df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(valueList=purrr::accumulate(value,c)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

However when I use this with certain other values, I get an error as per the question title. See below:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(56612,32323,96953,93074,15964,38483,11020,91474,62432,70463,89016,29826,85076,46258,18339,89016),
                 value=c(58,61,59,49,36,35,30,23,75,73,43,0,46,45,43,42))

df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(valueList=purrr::accumulate(value,c)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

`Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
Column valueList can't be converted from numeric to list`

Why is this happening?

Comment: In the second case, you don't have any repeated 'id', ie. the frequency is all 1

Comment: @akrun *almost* all have a frequency of 1; ID 89016 occurs twice

Comment: I think the issue would be the uneven structures created (`list` vs vector` when most of the frequency count is 1

Comment: You may either wrap in a `list` or `df %>% 
   dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
   dplyr::mutate(valueList= list(purrr::accumulate(value,c)))` or check if the element is a `list`, then process differently

Comment: Definitely not the same as the desired outcome in the first case above @akrun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What akrun probably meant was that you should wrap `accumulate` to make sure that it always returns a list,
because if you execute it on a single element,
it simply returns that element:

```
accumulate(c(1), c)
# [1] 1
accumulate(c(1, 2), c)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1

# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2
```

You can do that with:

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(valueList=as.list(purrr::accumulate(value, c))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

I *assume* that this happens because `dplyr` probably expects the result's structure to be compatible across all groups,
check for example:

```
bind_rows(tibble(a=list(1)),
          tibble(a=2))
# Error: Column `a` can't be converted from list to numeric
bind_rows(tibble(a=2),
          tibble(a=list(1)))
# Error: Column `a` can't be converted from numeric to list
```

But I'm not sure why it correctly handled your first example.

Comment: doesn't `as.list` achieve the same thing more simply